# Why does calling a closure vs a function defined inside a macro yield different results?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust, closures

This is a simplified example from some library code. For some reason, the function `m` is callable in that scope but the closure `n` isn't:

```rust
pub trait TestTrait {
    fn testFunc();
}

macro_rules! custom {
    ($body:expr) => {
        fn testFunc() {
            fn m() {}
            let n = || {};
            $body
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! int_custom {
    () => {
        impl TestTrait for i32 {
            custom!({
                m();
                n();
            });
        }
    };
}

int_custom!();

fn main() {
    println!("Test");
}
```

```
error[E0425]: cannot find function `n` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:20:17
   |
20 |                 n();
   |                 ^ not found in this scope
...
26 | int_custom!();
   | -------------- in this macro invocation
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Don't put line numbers in your code snippets. Code should be runnable, and random numbers in the source do not help that goal.

Comment: By the way, idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case` for variables, methods, macros, fields and modules; `UpperCamelCase` for types and enum variants; and `SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE` for statics and constants.

Comment: Your question is the same as the linked duplicate with `s/constant/function/`.